# How do I eliminate a harsh lighting issue on my cylindrical glossy model?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, geometry, faces

I am new to blender and have recently created my first model.  I created the mesh and then textured it, added a world environment texture, and rendered it only to find a very dark harsh "shadow" around the rear of my model.  However, the shadow only appears when I add a face to the back of the model to complete the whole mesh.  I have included pictures so you can see what I am talking about.

Without the rear face
[image: This is what the model looks like when the rear face of the cylinder is deleted]

With the rear face
[image: This is what the model looks like with the rear face included]

In the first picture you can see the model's cylindrical body WITHOUT it's rear face resulting in no shadow.  However, in the second picture, a face was added to the rear of the model resulting in a harsh shadow as shown.
I am using blender version 2.73

Comment: Let me guess, Subsurf modifier, and then a flat many-sided face on the back? That would be called an N-Gon, and is highly frowned upon in Blender as it brings a host of issues into the picture. Try adding an edge-loop near the N-Gon face on the back (`Ctrl`+`R`)

Comment: Yes that sounds about right although, the rear face is only made up of one side.  However, your solution fixed it, thank you! :)

Comment: I'll add an answer  then, glad it helped :)

Comment: BTW, I meant side as in edge ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are using a Subsurf modifier, and a flat many-edged face on the back. That would be called an N-Gon, and is highly frowned upon in Blender as it brings a host of issues into the picture. Quads (faces with 4 edges) are much prefered, as it they work best for almost all of the relevant calculations done by Blender.

This particular issue can be resolved by adding an edge-loop near the face on the back by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: It looks to me as though the blackened part is caused by the smooth shaded normals being interpolated across the sharp angle, not necessarily the n-gon.  In which case the extra loop cut you suggested would fix it.  If my theory is correct, adding an *edge split* modifier or enabling *auto smooth* should fix it as well.